# Really basic mpir questions

Tags: c, precision, floating-point-precision, pointer-arithmetic

I know this is a really dumb question but I was hoping someone could help.

I'm forced to use mpir for precision reasons so I have to translate all my c code for it. Basically I just need more significant figures of precision.

however, I'm really confused by the data types to use for my variable. I understand mpz_t is for integers. Since i'm storing numbers with lots of decimal places this obviously isn't appropriate as integers are just whole numbers

mpq_t is for rationals. Since i don't think each value stored would be a rational number i don't see how this would be appropriate.

mpf_t is for floating numbers. Since this has "limited precision" I don't see how this would be useful to use for my variables since the main reason I was told to use mpir was for increased precision.

I just want to be able to represent my numbers in an accurate way and the whole reason I was using this was because i was told it would help maintain accuracy when doing arithmetic between really big and small numbers. What data type am i supposed to use for mpir? I was told i needed greater than quadruple precision. :-(

I just find myself confused by the whole thing and need some guidance on what data type to use and how to determine the level of precision. Explained in a really simple way if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MPIR 2.6.0 documentation](http://www.mpir.org/mpir-2.6.0.pdf) (PDF link), Chapter 7:

> MPIR floating point numbers are stored in objects of type mpf_t and functions operating on
>   them have an mpf_ prefix.
>
> The mantissa of each float has a user-selectable precision, limited only by available memory. Each variable has its own precision, and that can be increased or decreased at any time.

It looks like it has various functions to help with setting your precision, in bits, such as `mpf_set_default_prec`, `mpf_get_prec`, and `mpf_set_prec`.

You should use `mpf_t` as the data type, and it is limited precision, but the advantage of MPIR is that you can set what that limit is. You can use 128 bits for the mantissa of the float, if you like. This would be more than 4x as accurate as a 32-bit float.

From the [Wikipedia on quadruple-precision floating-point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format), it looks like quadruple-precision means a significand/mantissa of 113 bits, so you will probably want to use at least 113-bit precision with MPIR to get that level of accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mpir.org/mpir-2.6.0.pdf

Page 48 of the documentation states that each floating point variable has user-selectable precision limited only by available memory.

They also write:

```
void mpf_set_prec (mpf_t rop, mp_bitcnt_t prec) [Function]

    Set the precision of rop to be at least prec bits. The value in 
    rop will be truncated to the new precision. This function requires 
    a call to realloc, and so should not be used in a tight loop.
```

Would a call to that function suit your needs?